# Fastest way to copy x elements of an array starting from an specific index

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm a beginner with C and am playing with pointer and arrays.

Let's say I have the following function

```
GetArrayValues(uint8**pValues, uint32 *pNumValues);
```

where:

```
**pValues points to the first element of the array

*pNumValues points to the number of values in the array
```

Let's suppose the array contains 100 uint8 elements.

Now each time I call the function `GetArrayValues()` I would like to copy all 30 elements starting from index 20 into a new array:

```
uint8 myInternalArray[30]
```

What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: If the buffers will never overlap, the fastest way is likely `memcpy`.

Comment: @JohnDoe For starters **pValues does not point to an array of values of the type uint8. It points to the first element of an array with elements type uint8 *.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks! I corrected it!

Comment: I noticed that you are "playing", but why would you want to have pointers-to-pointers for the array and a pointer to the length intead of the actual length? If you are a beginner, you should first be comfortable with simple function interfaces that only have one pointer indirection. Your first question should not be about "fastest" but how you can do that correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want something like this

```
void *arrcpy(const void *src, void *dest, size_t pos, size_t len, size_t elemsize)
{
    const unsigned char *csrc = src;

    memcpy(dest, csrc + pos * elemsize, len * elemsize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general; the fastest way to do something is to find a way to avoid doing it and then do nothing. For example, if the array and its copy aren't going to be modified, you can just use different pointers to the same data without copying. In a similar way, if something is rarely modified, you might be able to avoid the copy initially and then (rarely) do the copy if something actually is modified.

If you can't do that; then the second fastest way is to minimise the amount of work you don't avoid. For example; copying data involves reading the original data from one place and writing it to another place; but maybe you can create the copy when you create the original to avoid reading from the original later.

If you can't do that; then the third fastest way is using inline assembly or intrinsics. For example; for modern 80x86 CPU (with AVX2), if you copy 2 extra "unused" bytes then you can probably do it with 2 instructions (load 32 bytes into a register, then store the register elsewhere). For an extreme case, maybe you can keep the copy in a register and do it with a single load.

If you can't do that; then the fourth fastest way is probably using `memcpy()`. Note that the compiler might be able to optimize the code so that `memcpy()` becomes as good as it could have been with inline assembly or intrinsics; however, in this case you'd have to make sure the compiler knows that it can modify the 2 extra "unused" bytes - otherwise it'll have use a slower approach (to avoid corrupting something else that might be after the end of the 30-byte copy).